# xcode 4.5.2 cannot build simple c++ project (iosfwd)

Tags: xcode

I have upgraded Xcode to 4.5.2
I have created simple c++ project and haven't change any thing.
There is only one file main.cpp with following code

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

// insert code here...
std::cout << "Hello, World!\n";
return 0;
}
```

but when I build project I get one error
In file iosfwd

```
In file included from /Users/abhineet/Github/Wiretap/Wiretap/main.cpp:9:
In file included from   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/ c++/v1/iostream:38:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/ios:215:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/iosfwd:90:10: fatal error: 'wchar.h' file not found
```

I dont know why I'm getting this error
but when I run it in Xcode 4.5, there is no error

Comment: This may not help, but might point you in a good direction. My project failed to compile after upgrading to 4.5.2 because I had placed some #import files in my .pch file between an #ifdef __ OBJC __ #endif. After I removed the #ifdef line, it compiled.

Answer (score -2):

add ***using namespace std;*** right below the #include

Comment: This is bad coding style; could you specify where the namespace resolution error might be occurring?

Comment: The error is not about namespaces, it's about wchar.h not being found